# Restar/Sumar fechas creadas con el componente Carbon

Tags: mysql, laravel, carbon

Tengo un botón con el cual edito los estados de asistencia de trabajadores.
Explico:
Al dar clic al botón, tengo un método que guarda la fecha actual en un campo llamado 'inicio'. Lo que necesito es que al dar clic nuevamente al botón, se guarde la fecha actual en un campo llamado 'salida' y, a la vez, se guarde la duración de la jornada de trabajo restando los datos del campo 'salida' menos el los datos del campo 'inicio'.
Actualmente tengo el método de actualización de la siguiente manera:

```
    $worker = Workers::find($request -> id);
    if($worker -> status == false || $worker -> status == 0){

        $worker -> status = true;
        $assistence = Assistences::create([

            'start' => Carbon::now() -> toDateTimeString(),
            'end' => null,
            'duration' => 0

        ]);

    } else {

        $worker -> status = false;
        $assistence = Assistences::find($request -> id) -> latest();
        $assistence -> end = Carbon::now() -> toDateTimeString();
        $assistence -> duration = Carbon::now() -> toDateTimeString() - $assistence -> start;

    }

    $worker -> save();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente los datos se guardan así en la tabla

Comment: Las columnas son tipo datetime.

Comment: El primer bloque del If guarda el formato de fecha actual para saber la fecha y hora de llegada del trabajador, el segundo debería guardar la fecha actual en el campo de 'salida' y el resultado de la resta de la 'entrada' y 'salida' en un campo llamado 'duración'

Comment: Quiero obtener horas con minutos.